Django: How do I get from my error message into my code?
I am currently working on a Django code where I place a bid in the template that outbids the current bid.
view.py
def article(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_bid = request.POST["new_bid"]
        user_name = request.user
        get_article = Listing.objects.get(pk=id)

        try:
            if int(new_bid) < get_article.current_price:
                messages.error(request, "Your bid does't count. Bid is less than highest bid.")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("article", args=(id, )))
            elif get_article.price.bid is None:
                messages.error(request, "Entry is not a number or is none")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("article", args=(id, )))
        except AttributeError:
                messages.error(request, "Attribute Error")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("article", args=(id, )))

        
        if int(new_bid) > get_article.price.bid:
            bid_placement = Bid(
                bid = int(new_bid),
                user_name = user_name)
            bid_placement.save()
            get_article.price = bid_placement
            get_article.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("article", args=(id, )))
    else:
        get_article = Listing.objects.get(pk=id)
        listed = request.user in get_article.watchlist.all()

        return render(request, "auctions/article.html", {
            "get_article": get_article,
            "listed": listed
        })

model.py
class Bid(models.Model):
    bid = models.FloatField(default=0)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="user_bid")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bid}"

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    developer_id = models.ForeignKey(Games, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="developer_id")
    current_price = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.ForeignKey(Bid, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="price")
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    photo = models.URLField()
    watchlist = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name="user_watchlist")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} {self.description} {self.developer_id} {self.current_price} {self.photo} {self.price}"

article.html
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Article</h2>

    <ul><a href="{% url 'index' %}"></a>
        <img src="{{ get_article.photo }}" alt="picture">
        <li>Game: {{ get_article.title }}<br>
            Description: {{ get_article.description }}<br>
            Developer: {{ get_article.developer_id }}<br>
            Current Price: {{ get_article.price }}€<br>

        </li>
    </ul>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    My Bid: {{ get_article.price }} €<br>
    <form action="{% url 'article' id=get_article.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>Bid:</label>
        <input type="number" name="new_bid" min="0" placeholder="Bid" required><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Place Bid">
    </form>
    {% else %}
    <p>Please LogIn in to place a bid</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    <p style="color:red" {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

I am currently working on a code where I place a bid in the template that outbids the current bid. The problem is the following:
If a price is already entered in the database, then I can outbid it. However, if I as a user have not yet placed a bid, it is set to "None". My first bid then leads to an error message (Attribute Error). I assume I have to change something in models.py or view.py. But I'm just in the learning process. Everything went well up to this point, but now I'm stuck. Can anyone help me?
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

You have to handle the case where get_article.price is None. Something like elif get_article.price and get_article.price.bid is None: in the first if block and something similar in the second.

Yes. "int(new_bid) < get_article.current_price" leads to the correct output when I add a bid under the current price. But a higher bid leads to the AttributeError wich I "catch" with the except. But it should jump to the next if statement, the result (if int(new_bid) > get_article.price.bid)

And the Attribute error is: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bid'

If you get an AttributeError you return from the function, so you can't reach the next line in the code.

Ah, I see. Ok the AttributeError is in line -> if int(new_bid) > get_article.price.bid: ... I just shifted the except AtritbuteError to the end oof the code. So now try/except works correctly but I still have to find fix the error. But thank you so far.

if int(new_bid) < get_article.current_price: is the answer, omg as easy that. But sometimes a small advise kann help :) thanks
